# Best background techniques for sensor collection

Tags: android, background-service

I am designing an Android app that collects continuously inertial data (from accelerometers and gyroscopes) for experimental purposes, packs them into chunks and sends them to the cloud.

- I don't need real-time performances so I can store data into binary files and, when it's "convenient", I send them to the cloud
- The collection and relay need to run 24/7
- I am ok with one or two activities, no reactive UI and fancy stuff. Maybe one log in and the second one that starts all the processes

Up to know I have prototyped one activity that listen to sensors and fills a buffer with the readings. When the buffer is full a thread is spawned, in this thread I open a new file and write the bytes on it from the buffer. At some point I have to design the uploading module, when I have N files I will upload them to the cloud.

It seems to work in this way but I have a question:

Is it there a better design pattern for this kind of application, maybe with background techniques?

I know that there are many classes that can handle the job like JobSchedulers, background and foreground services (according to android docs background services have an enormous amount of limitations right now, I think I cannot use them) or jetpack WorkManager, but I am having a hard time in finding the right one, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 9, it appears as though the only real option for tracking Sensor events in the background is with Foreground Services...

**Pie Documentation**

> [Android 9 limits the ability for background apps to access user input and sensor data... If your app needs to detect sensor events on devices running Android 9, use a foreground service.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#bg-sensor-access)

**Sensor Documentation:**

> [it's best to detect sensor events either when your app is in the foreground or as part of a foreground service.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#only-gather-sensor-data-in-the-foreground)

Comment: If you don't want to work with this solution. IMO, it seems like Google Fit api would be the only other option